# React/Context related question: How to have multiple variables within provider value? I'm using functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const state = useState({
    isLightTheme: true,
    light: { syntax: '#555', ui: '#ddd', bg: '#eee' },
    dark: { syntax: '#ddd', ui: '#333', bg: '#555' },
})

const toggleTheme = () => {
    setState({ isLightTheme: !state.isLightTheme })
}
```

I tried the following but none of these work:

- Provider value={state, toggleTheme}
- Provider value={[state, toggleTheme]}
- Provider value {{state: state, toggleTheme: toggleTheme}}

I am using context.api

Answer (score 1):

You can add your toggleTheme method as part of your state:

```js
const state = useState({
    isLightTheme: true,
    light: { syntax: '#555', ui: '#ddd', bg: '#eee' },
    dark: { syntax: '#ddd', ui: '#333', bg: '#555' },
    toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme
})

const toggleTheme = () => {
    setState({ isLightTheme: !state.isLightTheme })
}
```

Then you can pull toggleTheme out in your consumer:

```js
   <UserConsumer>
      { ({ light, dark, toggleName }) => (
      <div onClick={toggleName}></div>
      )}
   </UserConsumer>
```

This is how I learned it.  I personally don't like putting methods in my state, but this does in fact work as a way to pass methods through your context within your state variable.

Comment: Just edited my question, I didn't compose it very well. This is what I meant...